# Building a python counter with rollover

Tags: python, oop

I need to create a message counter object -not to be confused with Python's Counter class.  The specification calls for a counter that is initialized to 0, then increments by 1 until it hits 4294967295, at which point it's supposed to cycle back over to 1.

I've implemented a  class to do this, but this is just the naive approach.  Is there a better way to achieve this goal ?

```
class MessageCounter():
  def __init__(self):
      self.value = 0
  def increment(self):
      if self.value < 4294967295:
          self.value += 1
      else:
          self.reset()
  def reset():
      self.value = 1
```

Comment: The magic number aside, this is a perfectly valid approach. What exactly are you uncomfortable with?

Comment: since this is a working piece of code with no specific issue with it, it may be more interesting to post it on CodeReview

Comment: `self.value = self.value+1 if self.value < 4294967295 else 1`

Comment: I would make `4294967295` a class attribute (e.g. `VALUE_CAP`) to remove the "magic number" and add some docstrings, but otherwise that seems fine.

Comment: If you use the constants approach like jonrsharpe says, you should use `2**32-1` instead of that number.

Comment: you could consider emulating a number, by defining methods such as `__add__` and `__iadd__`

Comment: Something interesting I found is that `4294967295 | x == 4294967295` is equal to `x <= 4294967295` for positive integers.

Comment: There's nothing that makes me particularly uncomfortable, it's just been my experience with Python that there's often some sort of totally awesome built in type that does everything you want, or some really cool lamda expression that turns 20 lines of code into 1.  I thought maybe I'd just see if someone knew a way of implementing this with something way more efficient.

Comment: I hadn't seen Stack Exchange's code review board before.  That's a better place to put this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to OO, you could create a generating function that yields numbers in sequence, forever. There are a number of ways to do this. In descending order of size and straightforwardness:

```
def count_loop(upper_limit):
    while True:
        for i in range(upper_limit):
            yield i
gen = count_loop(4294967295)
```

---

```
import itertools
gen = (i for _ in itertools.count() for i in range(4294967295))
```

---

```
gen = (i for _ in iter(int,1) for i in range(4294967295))
```

You would then retrieve your values by doing `next(gen)`.

```
>>> next(gen)
0
>>> next(gen)
1
>>> next(gen)
2
>>> next(gen)
3
```

(note: Python 2.7 users should use `xrange` instead of `range`. However, this may only work for max values smaller than 2^31)

Comment: Using an infinite generator is actually the most pythonic way to solve this problem (I'm actually fairly certain that generating infinite cycles is one of the first examples of a generator in the tutorials)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the reset you can just use the modulo operator:. It will "reset" to 0 instead of one, but that shouldn't matter since you initilized as 0.

```
def increment(self):
    self.value = (value + 1) % 4294967296
```

Comment: checking greater more efficient than mod function

Comment: I tend to not like modulo because it can be a very slow operation. Also, this does not reset to 1, but to 0. you need `(value % 4294967295) + 1`

Comment: Much, much, **much** more efficient than the modulo operator. Especially when the odds of rollover are very small compared to the number of times the modulo operator is called.

Comment: Yes, there is a performance issue with the modulo. But only when the second argument is not 2^n, in that case it will be optimized to `x & (y-1)` which could also be used in that case.

Answer (score -2):

I have an example, just more shorter.

```
class MessageCounter():
  def __init__(self):
      self.value = 0

  def increment(self, reset=False):
      self.value = self.value + 1 if self.value < 4294967295 and not reset else 1
```

Comment: why would there be a `reset` parameter in the `increment` function?

Comment: to eliminate reset function. It is just a proposal

Comment: I imagine to allow for manual resetting, but doesn't really make sense to be included in the check metho .

Comment: passing `message_counter.increment(reset=True)` seems counter intuitive, or even worse: `message_counter.increment(True)`, how do you read this thinking that it would reset?